# Facebook comments do not appear regularly

Tags: facebook-like, blogger, facebook-comments

I am using both the like button and the comment box on my blog; [vocabularioextenso.blogspot.com](http://vocabularioextenso.blogspot.com)

But the like button sometimes shows a correct number of likes and other times shows zero. Also, comments that I have received in a post do not appear regularly, and sometimes a warning is shown in a yellow box saying the url of that post is inaccessible.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by country specified redirection that blogger applies.

Here is an article that explains the Permanent Solution for this problem.

http://aslamise.blogspot.in/2013/04/facebook-comments-and-like-count-problem-in-blog-issue-solved.html